# Laravel cannot find a Controller Method (does not exist)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a new method in a BoController called "deleteBooking", the method is defined:

```
public function deleteBooking($id){
    $booking = Reservation::find($id);
    if($booking && $booking->delete()){
        try {
            $email = Mail::to($booking->user_email)->send(new Cancel($booking));
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }

        return redirect('admin/manager/home')->with('message','Réservation annulée!');
    }
    return redirect('admin/manager/home')->with('message','Réservation non annulée!');
}
```

But laravel at the endpoint says:

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method [deleteBooking] does not exist.
```

Other methods from the same class are linked to endpoints too, and work well.

Do you have any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the BoController and the route you are using?

Comment: Check out the routes - route is missing or maybe you have misspelled the function name on the route def. file (try php artisan route:list and compare the route and the function name)

Comment: `GET|HEAD | admin/booking/delete/{id}            |                        | App\Http\Controllers\BoController@deleteBooking` From Route list, `Route::get('booking/delete/{id}', 'BoController@deleteBooking');` from web.php, I will post the whole class if needed.

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump`?

Comment: I tried it, still not exist.

Comment: How you are trying to access the route on the link|button you are using to call the function (can you show the code)?

Comment: `{{ url('admin/booking/delete/'.$booking->id) }}` From the view, but now I'm just accessing the get method directly but same result for both, I tried to define a new method 'hello' that returns a hello message and gave me the same error.

Comment: But in your route you dont have the admin/ before the booking

Comment: Change your route to Route::get('admin/booking/delete/{id}', 'BoController@deleteBooking');

Comment: I have a prefix on the group called 'admin' that's why

Comment: Why don't you post you whole route file so we can analyze it.

Comment: Here you go: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88f4c4e29589180f1660ebb677de384bc217c260

Comment: You will need to check whether you have cached the routing or not. So follow the link - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#route-caching. Or clear the routing cache and create another one.

Comment: I did it already using artisan, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed, I've found another file called BoController, in another folder somehow and it was conflicting with the App\Http\Controllers one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that you have declared that function for some other request type other than the one you're trying to make. For example you put `Route::post('some-method', 'BoController@deleteBooking');` but you need to put either `Route::get(...)` or `Route::put(...)` or `Route::delete(...)`.

If it isn't that problem, then you probably misspelled it.

Comment: I changed names and everything still got that error, I checked how I spelled it also.

Comment: What kind of a request are you making to that action? is it a GET, a POST, PUT or DELETE?

Comment: It's a GET method

Comment: Can you show a snippet of your route declaration (eg. Route::get('name', 'BoController@deleteBooking')) ?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88f4c4e29589180f1660ebb677de384bc217c260 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue. Then I have figured out a issue pointed in composer install log, with following instance of log line:

`Class App\Http\Controllers\BlogController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/BlogControllerOld.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.`

Based on that I have found that one of the file renamed with **Old** suffix was creating conflict with the main file. So here I have to chhoseone of the following solutions:

1. To delete the file created for backup.
2. Or just rename the class in duplicated file to **BlogControllerOld**.

So its a good idea to check for issues with `composer install`

It will highlight the conflicts that can be fixed using one of the method above.
Once fixed using specified methods above issue `composer install` to apply the fix and regenerate autoloader.